# How does ASP.NET Core 6 bind handle responses when binding HttpContext to a handler?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-6.0, minimal-apis

I just ran into a major headache working on a site that uses ASP.NET Core 6 minimal APIs.

```
public class GetUsersEndpoint : EndpointBase
{
    /// <inheritdoc />
    public override WebApplication MapEndpoints(WebApplication app)
    {
        app.MapGet("/api/users/", GetUsersAsync);
        return base.MapEndpoints(app);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get a list of users
    /// </summary>
    [Authorize(Roles = AppRoles.SystemAdministrator),
     SwaggerOperation(Tags = new[] {"Users"})]
    private async Task<IResult> GetUsersAsync(HttpContext context)
    {
        await Task.Yield();
        return Results.StatusCode(400);
    }
}
```

No matter what I returned from the `GetUsersAsync` method above, ASP.NET Core 6 always returned an empty 200 response.

Finally, after about an hour of digging, I tried the following instead:

```
public class GetUsersEndpoint : EndpointBase
{
    /// <inheritdoc />
    public override WebApplication MapEndpoints(WebApplication app)
    {
        app.MapGet("/api/users/", GetUsersAsync);
        return base.MapEndpoints(app);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get a list of users
    /// </summary>
    [Authorize(Roles = AppRoles.SystemAdministrator),
     SwaggerOperation(Tags = new[] {"Users"})]
    private async Task<IResult> GetUsersAsync(HttpResponse response)
    {
        await Task.Yield();
        return Results.StatusCode(400);
    }
}
```

Note the `HttpContext` parameter is now `HttpResponse` instead.

And it worked fine. It seems to me that if ASP.NET Core 6 minimal API binds to a handler that receives `HttpContext` directly, it appears to delegate all handling of the response to the method and does not subsequently execute the `IResult` or anything else.

However, I cannot seem to find any documentation describing this behavior. Am I on the right track, or did I miss something obvious?

Comment: Have you checked this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/min-web-api?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#differences-between-minimal-apis-and-apis-with-controllers) whitch shows the different bewteen controller api and minimal Api and also some features  are not supported by minimal api?

Comment: That link says nothing about what I mentioned above.